# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' in Django

Tags: python, django

I get the 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' error when opening a URL which view is this one:

```
@login_required
def order_checkout_view(request):
    product_id = request.session.get("product_id") or None
    if product_id == None:
        return redirect("/")
    product = None
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    except:
        return redirect("/")
    user = request.user
    order_id = request.session.get("order_id")
    order_obj = None
    new_creation = False
    try:
        order_obj = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    except:
        order_id = None
    if order_id == None:
        new_creation = True
        order_obj = Order.objects.create(product=product, user=user)
    if order_obj != None and new_creation == False:
        if order_obj.product.id != product.id:
            order_obj = Order.objects.create(product=product, user=user)
    request.session['order_id'] = order_obj.id
    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, product=product, instance=order_obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        order_obj.shipping_address = form.cleaned_data.get("shipping_address")
        order_obj.billing_address = form.cleaned_data.get("billing_address")
        order_obj.mark_paid(save=False)
        order_obj.save()
        del request.session['order_id']
        return redirect("/success")
    return render(request, 'orders/checkout.html', {"form": form, "object": order_obj})
```

The exception location is in this line

```
if order_obj.product.id != product.id:
```

There's an existing product in the database, however does this mean in this case the Product is 'None'? What could be the problem here?

Comment: put a debugger in your code and anaylze, use the following "import pdb;pdb.set_trace()" some where in the code before you get exception, then the control will stop at the line, you can watch the values of product in the shell. Use 'n' to go to next line, 'c' for continue, ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: Is the product field nullable in the Order model? If so that might be the cause of your error, an order having no product.

Comment: Yes the file is nullable. The thing is why does it appear that the 'order' has no 'product' related to it. Shouldn't it have one as there's one in the database?

Comment: Is the Product in the product table or does the Order table have the product in its column? A Product being in the Product table does not mean an Order would have a product.

Comment: The Order model has a ForeignKey to the Product model where there are several items.

Comment: Try running this query in the shell `Order.objects.filter(product__isnull=True).count()`

Comment: Okay, so the problem is solved it was just a login issue so the order couldn't be created. Thank you very much for your help.